# Upload photo to Flickr with ASIHttpRequest

Tags: objective-c, upload, asihttprequest, photo, flickr

I'm trying to upload a photo to Flickr using ASIHttpRequest.
I can get the user to authorize the app and get the access token. Then when I try to upload a photo it fails with the following error

> "NO Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=3 "Authentication
>   needed" UserInfo=0x9757d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication
>   needed}"

image is the photo I want to upload,

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSUrl urlWithString:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/upload/"] autorelease];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(aJob.image);
[request setPostValue:FLICKR_SECRET_KEY forKey:@"api_key"];
[request setPostValue:accessToken forKey:@"auth_token"];
[request setData:data withFileName:fileName andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Any tip?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert using the flickr API but maybe this will help you getting things done: [Objective Flickr](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr)